# javascript variable reset button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a button which will change the value of "box1" or "value!" to = 0. I've spent hours trying different approaches, can someone please point me in the right direction.

```html
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
   function calculate() {
  var value1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var value2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  var myResult = value1 * value2;
  result.value = myResult;
 }
 function reset() {
  value1 = 0;
  }
  
  </script>
  
  <div><input id="box1" type="text" /> Value 1</div>
  <div><input id="box2" type="text"  />Value 2</div>
  <div><input id="result" />Answer</div>
  <div><button onclick="calculate()" value="text here" style="width: 139px">Calculate</button></div>
  <div><button onclick="reset()" value="text here5" style="width: 139px">reset</button></div>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('box1').value=0; ?

Comment: As far as I know JavaScript(very little) `value1 = 0` does not exist in the scope of `reset()` You must declare it and the initialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me ;)

```js
function calculate() {
  var value1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = value1 * value2;
  result.value = myResult;
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById('box1').value = 0;
  document.getElementById('box2').value = 0;
  document.getElementById('result').value = 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <input id="box1" type="text" />Value 1</div>
    <div>
      <input id="box2" type="text" />Value 2</div>
    <div>
      <input id="result" type="text" />Answer</div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="calculate()" value="text here" style="width: 139px">Calculate</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="reset()" value="text here5" style="width: 139px">reset</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset all the fields, following your style:

```
function reset() {
   document.getElementById('box1').value=0; 
   document.getElementById('box2').value=0;
   document.getElementById('result').value=0;   
}
```

Or, if you want to reuse those variables declaring them as global:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var el1;
var el2;
var res;

function calculate() {
    el1 = document.getElementById('box1');  
    el2 = document.getElementById('box2');
    res = document.getElementById('result');    
    var myResult = el1.value * el2.value;
    res.value = myResult;
}
function reset() {
    el1.value = 0;
    el2.value = 0;
    res.value = 0;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `value1` does not exist in the scope of your reset method.  It is defined in calculate.

You should refer to the box you wish to reset in your reset function:

```
document.getElementById('box1').value = 0;
```